# Test Devise registration controller with functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, functional-testing

I'm trying to test my registration controller (which overrides Devise's built in controller) but when I do the following test:

```
test "should create user" do
    post :create, user: { email: "temp12345@email.com", first_name: @user.first_name}
    assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
end
```

However, the response coming back says "You must sign up/sign in to continue" which makes no sense as I can do this manually from the browser to sign up a user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had the same issue.  Answer is in the [devise docs](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/test-helpers):

> 2) If you are testing Devise internal controllers or a controller that
>   inherits from Devise's, you need to tell Devise which mapping should
>   be used before a request. This is necessary because Devise gets this
>   information from router, but since functional tests do not pass
>   through the router, it needs to be told explicitly. For example, if
>   you are testing the user scope, simply do:

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
get :new
```